# MVC Application is working fine in IIS Express but not working in Local IIS web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I have  created a web application to open a file (Whatever like notepad, excel, PDF, etc.) in local directory. File is opening when running it in IIS Express but in IIS local Web server, it's not opening the file.

I have the files inside the project in Visual studio.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"D:// Path ");

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
var newestFile =
    (from file in fileList
    //where file.Contains(para)
    orderby file.CreationTime
    where file.FullName.Contains(para)
    select new { file.FullName, file.CreationTime })
    .Last();

Process.Start(newestFile.FullName);

return "";
```

Comment: Process.Start runs on the server, not client. Are you expecting the user to see these files open?

Comment: Yes.. User need to open the specified file in process.Start()

Comment: That won't work, they must download the file.

Comment: OKay thanks.. Can I have the idea to do that process? I'm with  MVC application

Comment: Google FilestreamResult

Comment: Thanks.. Let me check with this

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a virtual directory with path D:// Path. Try giving proper permissions to the folder.

Comment: Created virtual and given permission to folder for both IIS user as well as default app pool.. nothing working

Answer (score 0):

Give proper permission to IISUser for the folder in which you are storing the files.

Hope this would help.

Comment: I have checked and given permission to both IUSR as well as Default app pool

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a user permissions, check to see what security permissions are set for D:// Path and how they differ from your one that works.